# What happened to cooperative close voting?

Tags: support, dupehammer

In [voting to close this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734798/not-duplicate-how-to-trigger-when-action-in-seperate-thread-is-complete), it appears that SO only required my vote to make the closure, resulting in a rather unhappy punter.

IMO, the closure is completely correct... but... Why am I able to do this? What happened to democracy?

Comment: Ah, the irony...

Comment: real irony would be if this question was in turn [dupehammer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/dupehammer/info)ed by someone having gold badge in [meta-tag:support] tag

Comment: Look at it this way: no one has the `support` gold badge yet and thus a dupe hammer vote to close this one. :-P